# It is possible to Resize an iframe without reloading the frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hi Stack Overflow Community. 
I have a problem. I have a process with an iFrame.
This process have some Javascript to set iFrame height based on iFrame content. I think its not enough, so I decided to make an automatic resize of the iFrame height based on content changes without reloading any iFrame or process. Unfortunately, I tried but was unable to due to doubts. I searched everywhere in Stack Overflow but I didn't found the solution.

**Rules:**

- Auto Height resize in the iFrame.
- No reloads in the parent window or iFrame.
- No triggers, no Interval.
- Just everything automatic.

Window and iFrame are in the same domain.

Could you please help me?
Thanks, and sorry for bad english.

**My Actual CODE:**

```
if(document.getElementById("frame") != undefined)
{
    var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

        $(frame).load(function(){
            var frame_height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
            frame.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + frame_height + ' !important');
            console.log('its this loading?');
            contentBasedIframeResize(); //this is worthless, just testing. isn't dynamic right now. need fix.
        // As soon as the frame finish the load, this frame height will be based in the frame content
        });

        function contentBasedIframeResize()
        {
            var add_button = $(frame).contents().find(".some_obj"); //preparing the trigger
            var remove_button = $(frame).contents().find(".some_obj"); //preparing the trigger

            if(add_button != undefined)
            {
                $(add_button).click(function(){
                    var add_height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
                    frame.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + add_height + ' !important');
                });
            }

            if(remove_button != undefined)
            {
                $(remove_button).click(function(){
                    var remove_height = $("#frame").contents().find("#table_obj").height();
                    remove_height = parseInt(remove_height) + 100; //hardcoded
                    frame.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + remove_height + 'px !important');
                    console.log("its this working v2?");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you actually find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function resizeIframe(obj)
{
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

$('iframe').load(function(){
    resizeIframe(this);
});
```

Comment: What you write i already have in my code. The problem is, i will need a trigger or a reload anyway. Thanks anyway :)

EDIT: the trigger that I have done in my code isn't working for some reason. I will make it the maximum dynamically that i can and I will share with you.

Comment: Ok. But you should put your code in the question so we could see the problem more easily ;)

Comment: done my friend. i have a lot of undefined conditions for testing, because this code its global in my project. your solution its almost the same as mine, but your seems better with the frame selector as parameter in the function